# Blender 2.76b - Slow performance on Viewport Shading Material

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, 3d-view, performance

- I'm running Blender on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; I use Blender 2.76b. My problem is when I turn the Viewport Shading to Material Mode, it is very very slow. It is even much slower (much!) than the Rendered Mode. Literally, I can't even move the view naturally.
- The official site of Blender says that the version 2.76 is the last compatible with OpenGL 1.4 (That is the version that I have), therefore, should not present me any problem.
- I do not have a dedicated graphics card, but the integrated Intel chip. This, for its time, should not present problems of incompatibility due to Driver issues.

[UPDATE]

The problem persists in versions 2.75a, 2.76, 2.76a and 2.76b, I have not tried other older versions. There is an irrelevant performance improvement between version 2.75a and 2.76b.

Thanks, first of all.